# How can I setState on two array elements at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I tried to build a Timer Demo App. I used `setInterval` to auto count down the timer, but my initial state `timer` is an array with 2 elements, and I want to count down *on both timers together*.

In my code I just can count down one element if I pass an `id` argument into the function (like 1 or 2), but I want count down each together, how can I go about doing this?

[This is my demo in CodePen](https://codepen.io/Hiphopkiddz/pen/rzBGQG?editors=0011)

```
const timers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    time: 15,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    time: 20,
  },
];
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      timers,
    }

  }
  componentDidMount(){
    setInterval(() => {
      this.countDown();
    }, 1000);
  }
  countDown(id){
    const foundTimer = this.state.timers.find(timer => timer.id === id);
    foundTimer.time = foundTimer.time - 1;
    this.setState({timers: this.state.timers});
  }

  renderTimers(){
    return(
     this.state.timers.map((timer) =>{
      console.log(timer);
      return(
        <div key = {timer.id} >
          <div>{timer.time}</div>
        </div>
      )
    })
    )
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderTimers()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify `this.state.timers` with something like `Array#map` that maps original array elements to new ones. Don't mutate state directly, it's the source of all evil. For example:

```
countDown() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    timers: prevState.timers.map(timer => ({
      ...timer,
      time: timer.time - 1
    }))
  }));
}
```

This will map each of the timers to a new timer, without mutating state, where the new timers keep the same properties (via [object spread properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)) except it will change the `time` property of every timer to 1 less the current time.

If object spread properties isn't supported in your environment, use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  timers: prevState.timers.map(timer =>
    Object.assign(
      {},
      timer,
      { time: timer.time - 1 }
    )
  )
}));
```

This will do the same exact thing above, it will copy the properties from `timer` into an empty object `{}` (preventing mutation), then overriding the `time` property and decrementing it. It's just a more verbose version if your platform doesn't support object spread properties.

Also, consider passing `timers` as *a prop*, not as an array outside the class. Restrict variables to their narrowest scope possible.

Comment: This is an even better approach! =D

Comment: @Andrew Li I have another question, If I want to change just one array in the state (like the id of timers is 1 ), how can I do this without mustating?

Comment: @ChamperWu If you want, you could ask a new question because that's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @AndrewLi Okay, I have asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283826/how-can-i-setstate-on-just-one-array-element-at-once

Answer (score 1):

Alright first of all mutating the state is not a good idea, it can lead to unexpected side effects that can give you a real headache down the line. It is a good practice to never mutate the state. A way to achieve what you want to without mutating the state can be as follows:

```
...
countDown() {
  const newTimers = this.state.timers.map(t => Object.assign({}, t, { time: t.time - 1}));
  this.setState({ timers: newTimers });
}
...
```