# How can I setState on just one array element at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner of ReactJS and javascript

I have ask a question about [How can I setState on two array elements at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257033/how-can-i-setstate-on-two-array-elements-at-once)

At that question the responder tell me don't mutate the state anyway.

But I have another question, If I want to stop the countdown timer by using `clearInterval()`, when the timer is arrived 0.

In my new attempt at codePen [Timer Demo 2](https://codepen.io/Hiphopkiddz/pen/brGWPd?editors=0011),

I use the `find()` method to find the element which time is 0, and use `clearInterval` to stop count down, but if one element's time is arrived 0 and another is not, there are all stopped.

How can I do to fix it?

```
const timers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    time: 5,
    timeIsUp: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    time: 10,
    timeIsUp: false,
  },
];
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      timers,
    }
    this.time_controller = 0;

  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.time_controller = setInterval(() =>{
      this.countDown();
    }, 1000)
  }
  countDown(){
    const foundTimers = this.state.timers.map(timer => ({
      ...timer,
      time: timer.time-1
    }));
    this.setState({timers: foundTimers});
    const foundTimer = foundTimers.find(timer => timer.time === 0 );
    if(!!foundTimer){
      clearInterval(this.time_controller);
    }
  }

  renderTimers(){
    return(
     this.state.timers.map((timer) =>{
      return(
        <div key = {timer.id} >
          <div>{timer.time}</div>
        </div>
      )
    })
    )
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderTimers()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: @AndrewLi So I need to add time_controller into the array element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with state management, it's simple logic:

1. Don't turn off the interval until you've counted down all the timers.
2. Don't reduce the time of timers that have already reached zero.

Side note: There isn't really any reason for the `timeIsUp` flags, is there? `time === 0` means time is up, doesn't it? Duplicating state opens the door to bugs where you update it in one place but not others.

Something along these lines, but the details aren't as important as the concepts:

```
countDown() {
  let updated = false;
  let keepTicking = false;
  const updatedTimers = this.state.timers.map(timer => {
    // Note that if we don't modify `timer`, we return it for reuse
    if (timer.time > 0) {
      timer = {...timer, time: timer.time - 1};
      updated = true;
      keepTicking = timer.time > 0;
    }
    return timer;
  });
  if (updated) {
    // We changed somthing, update
    this.setState({timers: updatedTimers});
  }
  if (this.time_controller !== 0 && !keepTicking) {
    // No more active timers, stop ticking
    clearInterval(this.time_controller);
    this.time_controller = 0;
  }
}
```

Note that I clear the timer handle when we clear the timer, so we know whether it's running.

Note that in that example, I take the pragmatic approach of a `map` callback with side-effects (setting the `updated` and `keepTicking` flags). I don't have a problem with localized side-effects like that, but there is a significant movement out there that would.

The non-side-effecty version would at least partially loop the timers more than once:

```
countDown() {
  const timers = this.state.timers;
  // Need to update?
  if (timers.find(t => t.time > 0)) {
    const updatedTimers = timers.map(timer => (
      // If we don't change a timer, we can reuse it
      timer.time === 0 ? timer : {...timer, time: timer.time - 1}
    );
    this.setState({timers: updatedTimers});
  }
  // Done ticking?
  if (this.time_controller !== 0 && updatedTimers.every(t => t.time === 0)) {
    clearInterval(this.time_controller);
    this.time_controller = 0;
  }
}
```

Note how the code is cleaner (because we express each thing we're doing on its own only when we need to) but less efficient (we may have to work hard to find that timer near the end that needs updating and keeps us ticking). 90% of the time, efficiency doesn't matter, `timers` will be less than several thousand entries long. So there's an argument for it.

Comment: How could I do if I don't turn off the interval and stop count down?

Comment: @ChamperWu: You just don't reduce `time` if `time` is already 0. I've added some code, but it's the concepts that are important.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, since you've already added code, should I delete my answer?

Comment: @AndrewLi: FWIW, I don't think you need to.

Comment: Thanks to you guys, I so appreciate it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the code lines 15, there is one extra bracket

Comment: @ChamperWu: Fixed. Also added some rambling notes on the code... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I add `timeIsUp` flag because i will try to add button to pause or continue the timer at next step, maybe that will be next question...I think so x__x